# flex with textinput not working in my react native app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to extend the TextInput to the entire screen and not set a definite width.
To do that I know we have to set "flex:1"
But it doesn't seem to work at all.
What is wrong here?? I want the TextInput to be stretched with the Button next to it.

```
 <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch' , flexDirection: 'row'}}>

        <TextInput value="nil" style={{ backgroundColor:"grey", height: 40}} textAlign='center'/>
        <Button title="V" onPress={()=>{this.dropList()}} />

        </View>
```

[image]

I want something like this. How do I get this???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grid in your `View`, adding `grid-template-columns` for the columns width, like:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3rem;
width: 100%;
```

With inline styles (not recommended at all):

```
{{ display: 'grid'; gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 3rem'; width: '100%' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the `flex` property on the parent whereas it needs to be applied on the `TextInput` itself.

**Bonus**: You don't need to set `flexDirection` to `row` because that's the default.

Here's a pure HTML, CSS example to show what I mean.

```css
.view {
 display: flex;
}
.view input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='view'>
  <input/>
  <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```